# Locate bad memory access on Solaris

Tags: memory-management, solaris, valgrind

On Linux, FreeBSD and other systems I have valgrind for checking for memory errors like invalid reads and similar. I really love valgrind. Now I have to test code on Solaris/OpenSolaris and can't find a way to get information on invalid reads/writes in an as nice way (or better ;-)) as valgrind there.

When searching for this on the net I find references to [libumem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libumem), but I get only reports about memory leaks there, not invalid access. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dbx included with the Sun Studio compilers includes memory access checking support in its "Run Time Checking" feature (the `check` subcommand).  See:

- [Solaris Studio 12.4 dbx manual: Chapter 9: Using Runtime Checking](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37069_01/html/E37078/blahb.html)
- [Debugging Applications with Sun Studio dbx, dbxtool, and the Thread Analyzer](http://developers.sun.com/sunstudio/overview/topics/debug_index.html)
- [Leonard Li's Weblog: Runtime Memory Checking](http://blogs.oracle.com/janitor/entry/runtime_memory_checking)

The related "Sun Memory Error Discovery Tool" is also available from 
http://cooltools.sunsource.net/discover/

Comment: hm, i had been there and forgotabout it ... playing with the bcheck wrapper now and trying to get it in my automated test suite.

Comment: There is now also an [experimental/partial port of valgrind to Solaris](https://bitbucket.org/setupji/valgrind-solaris) that was made by a student as part of their [master thesis project](https://dip.felk.cvut.cz/browse/pdfcache/pavlupe1_2012dipl.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Since version 3.11.0, Valgrind does run on Solaris.
See [Release Notes](http://valgrind.org/downloads/current.html) and [Supported Platforms](http://valgrind.org/info/platforms.html).

More precisely, **x86/Solaris** and **amd64/Solaris** is now supported.
Support for **sparc/Solaris** is still in works.

Comment: Just to mention, you have to have at least Solaris 11. In particular, Solaris 10.X is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

[watchmalloc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1465/watchmalloc-3malloc.html#scrolltoc) is a quite useful library that can be dynamically loaded for your program (usually no need for recompiling) and then sets watchpoints at all the usually problematic memory locations, like freed areas or after an allocated memory block.
If your program accesses one of these invalid areas it gets a signal and you can inspect it in the debugger.

Depending on the configuration problematic areas can be watched for writes only, or also for reads.