# profiling in solaris

Tags: profiling, solaris

Can anyone suggest a good tool to profile a program compiled with SunCC compiler.
Also please suggest a good equivalent of valgrind for the same.

Comment: Keep It Simple: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024

Comment: For money, check out Zoom: http://www.rotateright.com/

Comment: Hear, hear... Their SunCC compiler is a turd. It regularly crashes because it uses up all swap space. I still don't know how much space is needed to compile a program with SunCC. Also see [How much swap space does Solaris 11.3 need to run a compiler?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/458256/56041)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DTrace](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/technologies/dtrace-1930301.html) is the best tool for profiling [in] the universe.

> DTrace is a comprehensive dynamic
>   tracing framework for the Solaris™
>   Operating Environment. DTrace provides
>   a powerful infrastructure to permit
>   administrators, developers, and
>   service personnel to concisely answer
>   arbitrary questions about the behavior
>   of the operating system and user
>   programs.

It's not marketing, it really allows just that.

> The [Solaris Dynamic Tracing Guide](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=solaris11&id=OSDTG)
>   describes how to use DTrace to
>   observe, debug, and tune system
>   behavior. The DTrace guide also
>   includes a complete reference for
>   bundled DTrace observability tools and
>   the D programming language.

DTrace is also available in Mac OS X, (there's a nice GUI for it, Instruments), and a FreeBSD port that has only kernel mode providers is also available.

Answer (score 1):

The Sun Studio compilers include [Performance Analyzer](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18659_01/html/821-1379/index.html) for profiling and [Memory Runtime Checking](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18659_01/html/821-1380/blahb.html#scrolltoc) features in the dbx debugger.

See also the answers to [Locate bad memory access on Solaris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881343/locate-bad-memory-access-on-solaris/1882039).

Answer (score 0):

On SPARC hardware, you may want consider IBM Rational Quantify for performance profiling.

On the cheap, you can get away with `pstack` sampling, `prstat -vL`, and instrumenting your application with `gethrtime()`.